# Find the username and password in a request header and sensor it

Tags: php, regex, lookbehind

I'm receiving a complete request header from a third party. I need to hide the password and username.

```
Php-Auth-Pw:     p@ssword
Php-Auth-User:   testuser
```

How can I make it to look like this

```
Php-Auth-Pw:     ******
Php-Auth-User:   ******
```

I don't fully understand regular expressions just yet, and I've just read something about lookbehinds.

I've found this;

```
(?<=\Php-Auth-Pw:\s)(\w+)
(?<=\Php-Auth-User:\s)(\w+)
```

But what would be the correct way to do this with the PHP flavor?

Comment: *"Sending usernames and password through headers is not safe!"* It is safe, just not in this implementation. See [BAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and [more](https://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace them with a single call to `preg_replace`:

```
$s = preg_replace('~\bPhp-Auth-(?:Pw|User):\s*\K\S+~', '******', $s);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aLsaDe/1)

**Details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `Php-Auth-` - a literal char sequence `Php-Auth-`
- `(?:Pw|User)` - either a `Pw` or `User` substring
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - a match reset operator
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace characters